# Git master ahead of origin/master weird problems

Tags: git, bitbucket

Hopefully, someone can help me out because I've tried a bunch of things and it appears my system is in some weird state.

The way I am running the system, I am running, essentially, a test environment on my local computer.  I do various changes etc locally.  I then push to bitbucket, ideally making origin/master the ideal production branch.

The Production server I utilize pulls only from origin.  There are no changes made on the production server, so there are no unpushed commits.

The link between my local test environment and the origin works as expected.  I'm doing it through GitKraken.  I can see the origin/master and local master, and various other branches and they are all where I expect them to be.

**The problem is the production server:**

When I run "git pull http://.......bitbucket....git master
It pulls everything down and acts like it is in the correct commit for origin/master.

However, it says it is 26 commits ahead of origin/master.

I tried running `git branch -a` and it shows 1 local branch and 2 remote branches. However, there should be four remote branches, not 2.

Additionally, it seems like I can do anything to pull the correct origin/master location.  It always thinks it is at the commit 26 behind.

I have tried git reset --hard origin/master, and that put me to what it thinks is the origin/master, the commit 26 behind where it should be.

My theories as to why this is occurring are as follows:

- The commit it is stuck on was the last commit by the previous developer. The repo was set up by this previous dev and his account.  My account has admin access to the repo, but I was wondering if there could be a cause here.
- There is a git command I'm not using properly that is meant to pull information from the origin.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Edit:
Some clarification on recent comments.**

```
git fetch, git pull, git fetch origin
```

all provide the following error:

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://djprior@bitbucket.org': No such device or address.
```

I can only seem to get anything by running:

```
git pull https://{username}:{password}@bitbucket.org/{account}/{repo}.git master
```

I was under the impression that if my 'git pull ....' command is working, then it should run a git fetch at the same time, updating the remote branches correctly.

Running "git reset —hard origin/master" pushes me back to the commit 26 commits behind the correct one. (presumably because git fetch is failing)

After reading comments perhaps there is a problem with my git/config.

See below:

```
   [core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
   [remote "origin"]
    url = https://{username}@bitbucket.org/{account}/mii.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   [branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Why are you saying `git pull http://.......bitbucket....git master`? You are not pulling from origin? If you have two remotes why don't you give them both names?

Comment: `git pull <specific-url>` behaves a bit differently from `git pull origin` due to gitconfigs like `remote.origin.fetch` even if `origin` refers to right the specific url. So, try `git pull origin` instead.

Comment: `git pull` (With no args) will probably already do what you are expecting. If there are errors or local commits`git fetch; git reset —hard origin/master` Will fix that. The confusion in the question is because there’s no direct or indirect `git fetch` in your workflow so nothing is updating the locally-stored remote references.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: If the above doesn’t help please edit the question to include your `.git/config` and show, do not describe, what you are doing and the outcome.

Comment: I have updated the post with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

First fetch all the updates from the remotes

**git fetch**

If you do not have any local changes run below, to reset you local branch to the version on master

**git reset --hard origin/master**

After that try a,
**git pull**
it will say that branch is already up to date

Answer (score 0):

As [ElpieKay noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74333082/git-master-ahead-of-origin-master-weird-problems#comment131229177_74333082) and [matt asked about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74333082/git-master-ahead-of-origin-master-weird-problems#comment131229143_74333082) in comments, the culprit here is your use of a raw URL:

> ```
> git pull http://.......bitbucket....git master
> ```

It's important to remember a number of separate things here:

1. `git pull` = `git fetch` + a second command of your choice.
2. `git fetch` is what obtains commits and updates *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master`.<sup>1</sup>
3. For `git fetch` to update remote-tracking names, `git fetch` *must* be given a *remote* name like `origin`.

In particular, if you give `git fetch` a URL, Git *will not* look to see if some remote in your `.git/config` has that URL.  It will just connect directly to whatever answers *at* that URL, and obtain commits from there.  Since there's no *remote* involved here—remotes are the *names* like `origin`—as there's only a URL, Git will not update any remote-tracking names (which are more or less<sup>2</sup> formed by shoving the remote name, `origin`, in front of the branch name that `git fetch` can see when whatever answered at the URL lists out their branch names).

The end result is that your own `origin/master`—the one that you're now seeing as being "ahead of"—remains sadly out of date.  Running `git fetch origin` *instead of* `git fetch http://...` will fix it.  This is true even if you invoke `git fetch` via the fancy `git pull` two-commands-in-one operation.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, in modern documentation (older Git documentation does not have a consistent term).  But they're not *branch* names, so this is like calling an automobile a "mechanized horse carriage" because it emulates the old horse-powered carriage.

<sup>2</sup>It's both more and less, for [hysterical reasons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html) having to do with the tortuous path by which "remotes" and "remote-tracking names" came about in Git.  In particular the "refs" on the remote go through a mapping specified by one or more *refspecs*.  The default refspec for a remote named *`R`* transforms `refs/heads/text` into `refs/remotes/R/text`, but you can build your own refspecs, and if you do, Git obeys them.

Comment: git fetch has the following error: "Command 'git fetch' failed with return code 128 and error message. fatal: could not read Password for 'https://{username}@bitbucket.org': No such device or address". Same with git fetch origin. Same with "git pull". The only way I can seemingly get a response is with "git pull https://{username}:{password}@bitbucket.org/{account}/{repo} master."

Comment: That indicates that you are running `git fetch origin` in some sort of non-interactive setup, and `remote.origin.url` is set to an `https://` URL that requires a user name and password. Presumably your bitbucket setup allows fetching at `http://bitbucket.org/...` without a user name and password, so perhaps you want to set the URL to that.

Comment: Note that `git remote set-url` is the formal way to set the URL stored under a remote name like `origin`, but you can also edit `.git/config` directly. If this were my own system, though, I'd investigate using ssh with an appropriate "machine access" ssh key for any non-public repository here.